# Reset pagination on sorting - Mui-X DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I have a Material-UI `DataGrid` component, and I want it to reset pagination on sorting (see code below).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const Table: React.FC<Readonly<{}>> = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DataGrid
        onSortModelChange={() => {
          // <------------------------ Here I want to reset pagination on sort
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution (use the useGridApiRef)

- Step 1: Import the `useGridApiRef` from `@mui/x-data-grid`
- Step 2: Initialise the `apiRef` (by invoking the `useGridApiRef` function)
- Step 3: Use the `apiRef` (in the `DataGrid` component)
- Step 4: Define the `restorePaginationState` function.

  - `apiRef.current.exportState();` will fetch the current state.
  - `apiRef.current.restoreState();` will set the new state.
- Step 5: Invoke the `restorePaginationState` function on `onSortModelChange` events.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useGridApiRef } from '@mui/x-data-grid'; // <---------- Step 1


const Table: React.FC<Readonly<{}>> = () => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef(); // <---------- Step 2

  const restorePaginationState = () => {  // <---------- Step 4
    const state = apiRef.current.exportState(); 
    const restoredState = {
      ...state,
      pagination: {
        ...state.pagination,
        paginationModel: {
          ...state.pagination?.paginationModel,
          page: 0, // <-- Set the page to the first page
          pageSize: 5, // <-- Specify the pageSize based on the requirements of your grid.
        },
      },
    };
    apiRef.current.restoreState(restoredState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DataGrid
        apiRef={apiRef}    // <---------- Step 3
        onSortModelChange={() => {
          restorePaginationState(); // <---------- Step 5
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```